# str.Split(".") not working in C# interactive window but work in C# .Net core project?

Tags: c#, .net-core, .net-core-3.1

(visual studio 2019, .Net core 3.1)

The following expression got error in C# interactive window.

```
"".Split("")
(1,10): error CS1503: Argument 1: cannot convert from 'string' to 'char'
```

[image: #]

Which assembly is required for the method? Visual Studio shows the method is defined in `C:\Program Files\dotnet\packs\Microsoft.NETCore.App.Ref\3.1.0\ref\netcoreapp3.1\System.Runtime.dll`

Answer (score 5):

The `string.Split` overloads that take a single string as a parameter (as opposed to an array) are new in .NET Core 2.0.

C# Interactive runs against .NET Framework, so it will never gain those APIs.

You can verify this by reading `System.Runtime.InteropServices.RuntimeInformation.FrameworkDescription` from inside the Interactive dialog.

Answer (score 2):

The overload you're trying to use that takes a string as the first parameter was added in net-core. You can see the documentation for [it here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.split?view=netcore-3.1#System_String_Split_System_String_System_StringSplitOptions_).

In regular .NET framework, this overload does not exist. You can see the overloads [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.split?view=netframework-4.8).

C# interactive is running against framework. You can see this by running `Console.WriteLine(Environment.Version);` in your interactive shell and getting back a value like `4.0.30319.*****` instead of something like `3.1.1`. You won't have access to the core BCL from C# interactive until a version of C# interactive that works with core ships.